# Alert when a text box is left empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

Four text boxes are in a JSP page. After entering first text box, when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the focus moves to the second text box. Similarly the focus will be on 3rd and 4th text box after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox3"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox4"/>
```

If I move from the first to the third text box without filling the second text box, then I want to have an alert come as "2nd text box cannot be empty". Similarly after entering data on first, second if I am moving to the fourth text box without filling the third text box, then I want an alert as "3rd text box cannot be empty". And after the alert the focus must be on that empty text box again, the focus must not move further. How can I do this?

Comment: You have just posted your homework question here. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Please read the first point here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged the question with jQuery so I'll give you a jQuery solution. You may want to make the selector a bit more specific, depending on your HTML:

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    if(!this.value) {
        alert("Text box " + ($(this).index() + 1) + " cannot be empty.");
        this.focus(); //Keep focus on this input
    }
});
```

This binds an event handler to the `blur` event of the elements (which fires when the field loses focus, be it through pressing tab, clicking elsewhere or any other method of changing focus). The event handler checks whether the field has a value, and if not it alerts a message, using the jQuery `index` method to get the index of the element relative to its siblings.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgxaK/1/).

Comment: ya it is showing alert but focus will not be moved to 3rd text box if 2nd text box is empty, if i am moving to 3rd text box without filling 2nd text box then alert will come and also focus will be on 2nd text box again to enter data

Comment: i have just added that one in last sentence of my question

Comment: @student - I've edited the code. You just need to give focus back to the current `input`.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked but when when i am moving to 4th text box without filling 3rd one then alert is coming as "Text box 0 cannot be empty" but it should be "Text box 3 cannot be empty"

Comment: @student - Are the elements all children of the same parent? If they are spread out between different elements, the `index` method will not work the way you want it to.

Comment: ya they are children of the same parent